# How to configure Typesafe Activator not to use user home?

Tags: sbt, typesafe-activator

I'd like to configure Typesafe Activator and it's bundled tooling not to use my user home directory - I mean `~/.activator` (configuration?), `~/.sbt` (sbt configuration?) and especially `~/.ivy2`, which I'd like to share between my two OSes.
Typesafe "documentation" is of little help.

Need help for both Windows and Linux, please.

Comment: So far I tried to dig launch script (activator.bat on windows) but it only references ```%UserProfile%``` for ```CFG_FILE_HOME``` and ```CFG_FILE_VERSION```, and even changing that has no effect on where ```.activator``` directory is created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Command Line Options](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#Command+Line+Options) in the official documentation of sbt:

- `sbt.global.base` - The directory containing global settings and plugins (default: `~/.sbt/0.13`)
- `sbt.ivy.home` - The directory containing the local Ivy repository and artifact cache (default: `~/.ivy2`)

It appears that `~/.activator` is set and used in the startup scripts and that's where I'd change the value.

It also appears (in `sbt/sbt.boot.properties` in `activator-launch-1.2.1.jar`) that the value of `ivy-home` is `${user.home}/.ivy2`:

```
[ivy]
  ivy-home: ${user.home}/.ivy2
  checksums: ${sbt.checksums-sha1,md5}
  override-build-repos: ${sbt.override.build.repos-false}
  repository-config: ${sbt.repository.config-${sbt.global.base-${user.home}/.sbt}/repositories}
```

It means that without some development it's only possible to change `sbt.global.base`.

```
➜  minimal-scala  activator -Dsbt.global.base=./sbt -Dsbt.ivy.home=./ivy2 about
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-launcher/minimal-scala/project
[info] Set current project to minimal-scala (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-launcher/minimal-scala/)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.5
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-launcher/minimal-scala/}minimal-scala 1.0
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.11.1
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.4
```

If you want to see under the hood, you could query for the current values of the home directories for sbt and Ivy with `consoleProject` command (it assumes you started `activator` with `activator -Dsbt.global.base=./sbt -Dsbt.ivy.home=./ivy2`):

```
> consoleProject
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
import sbt._
import Keys._
import _root_.sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.CorePlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin
import currentState._
import extracted._
import cpHelpers._
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_60).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> appConfiguration.eval.provider.scalaProvider.launcher.bootDirectory
res0: java.io.File = /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-launcher/minimal-scala/sbt/boot

scala> appConfiguration.eval.provider.scalaProvider.launcher.ivyHome
res1: java.io.File = /Users/jacek/.ivy2
```

*Iff* you're really into convincing Activator to use `sbt.ivy.home`, you have to change `sbt/sbt.boot.properties` in `activator-launch-1.2.2.jar`. Just follow the steps:

1. Unpack `sbt/sbt.boot.properties` out of `activator-launch-1.2.2.jar`.

   ```
   jar -xvf activator-launch-1.2.2.jar sbt/sbt.boot.properties
   ```
2. Edit `sbt/sbt.boot.properties` and replace `ivy-home` under `[ivy]`.

   ```
   ivy-home: ${sbt.ivy.home-${user.home}/.ivy2}
   ```
3. Add the changed `sbt/sbt.boot.properties` to `activator-launch-1.2.2.jar`.

   ```
   jar -uvf activator-launch-1.2.2.jar sbt/sbt.boot.properties
   ```

With the change, `-Dsbt.ivy.home=./ivy2` works fine.

```
scala> appConfiguration.eval.provider.scalaProvider.launcher.bootDirectory
res0: java.io.File = /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-launcher/minimal-scala/sbt/boot

scala> appConfiguration.eval.provider.scalaProvider.launcher.ivyHome
res1: java.io.File = /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-launcher/minimal-scala/ivy2
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. I put ```-D...``` options in ```~/.activator/activatorconfig.txt``` - this one should be different for each OS anyway, since paths are different. Thank you for thorough explanation.

Comment: BTW I did report this issue at the time, but forgot to attach here. It seems to be still open https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/585

Answer (score 3):

I was experimenting with this today. After a while, it seems to me like this could be the best thing to do:

**Windows:**

```
setx _JAVA_OPTIONS "-Duser.home=C:/my/preferred/home/"
```

**Linux:**

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Duser.home=/local/home/me'
```

Then you should be good to go for any Java Program that wants to store data in your home directory.

Comment: Should it not be: `export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Duser.home=/local/home/me'`?

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Jacek's answer, another way that worked for me to set the `.ivy2` directory was to use the sbt `ivyConfiguration` task. It returns configuration settings related to ivy, including the path to the ivy home (the one which defaults to `~/.ivy2`).

Simply add these few lines to the `build.sbt` file in your project :

```
ivyConfiguration ~= { originalIvyConfiguration =>
  val config = originalIvyConfiguration.asInstanceOf[InlineIvyConfiguration]
  val ivyHome = file("./.ivy2")
  val ivyPaths = new IvyPaths(config.paths.baseDirectory, Some(ivyHome))
  new InlineIvyConfiguration(ivyPaths, config.resolvers, config.otherResolvers,
    config.moduleConfigurations, config.localOnly, config.lock,
    config.checksums, config.resolutionCacheDir, config.log)
}
```

It returns a new ivy configuration identical to the original one, but with the right path to the ivy home directory (here `./.ivy2`, so it'll be located just next to the `build.sbt` file). This way, when sbt uses the `ivyConfiguration` task to get the ivy configuration, the path to the `.ivy2` directory will be the one set above.

It worked for me using sbt `0.13.5` and `0.13.8`.

**Note**: for sbt versions `0.13.6` and above, the construction of the `InlineIvyConfiguration` needs an additional parameter to avoid being flagged as deprecated, so you might want to change the last line into :

```
new InlineIvyConfiguration(ivyPaths, config.resolvers, config.otherResolvers,
  config.moduleConfigurations, config.localOnly, config.lock,
  config.checksums, config.resolutionCacheDir, config.updateOptions, config.log)
```

(note the additional `config.updateOptions`)

Answer (score -1):

I had that same problem on Mac. I erased the directory in user home directory named .activator and all related folder. After that run activator run command on terminal. Activator download all of the folder which I deleted. Than problem solved.

Comment: This does not answer the question, it is about whether you can have the files placed elsewhere - not how to delete or restore them.